# UIActivityIndicatorView animation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiwebview

i have a tableview controller, when i select a row its pushing another view controller. In that view controller 's loadView  i have to request a url. it will take 5 or 10 secs to complete the request. i have to show UIActivityIndicatorView for that  delay . I have a UIActivityIndicatorView  in my table view didSelectRowAtIndexPath and  I'd like to "start" and "stop" animation. But it is not starting the animation  before it pushing the view controller. so that its not visible when the delay hapnd. i cant use uiwebview due to  some reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[activityindicator startAnimating];
timer=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0
                                       target:self 
                                     selector:@selector(CallThread) 
                                     userInfo:nil 
                                      repeats:YES];

-(void)CallThread
{
  //do your url request process
  [activityindicator stopAnimating];
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I really don't get this answer: it just fires a continuous timer with an interval of 0 (meaning a maximum available frequency) and what's worse: nothing stops this endless timer! In addition it shouldn't even have any impact, as it just stops the indicator exactly 0 seconds after it started?!

Answer (score 1):

Try posting the code in your didSelectRowAtIndexPath.  You're probably downloading the url synchronously, which is causing your delay.  Try using the asynchronous methods of NSUrlConnection:  http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001836-BAJEAIEE