# UIActivityIndicatorView delay after button press

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, selector, uiactivityindicatorview

I have a segmented control created programmatically, with a selector:

```
[control addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentedControlIndexChanged:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

The control works fine.

In the function `segmentedControlIndexChanged` the first step is to cue a UIActivityINdicatorView:

```
[loadWheel startAnimating];
```

Then a process is carried out, and a segue happens. All this works fine.

The problem is that the Activity Indicator seems to delay a bit, and by the time the wheel loads on the screen the processes have almost finished and the view is changed.

The total time between changing the control and the view changing is about 1.5 seconds, but the indicator shows up around 1.2 seconds. Is there a way to quicken the loading of the wheel?

*Additional Info*

The wheel is set up in the .h file:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView *loadWheel;
```

And is synthesized in the .m file:

```
@synthesize loadWheel;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at this quesiton:

[UIActivityIndicatorView animation delayed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17530659/uiactivityindicatorview-animation-delayed)

and this as well
[UIActivityIndicatorView animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165048/uiactivityindicatorview-animation)

It appears you want to start your animation first, and then start your task on a different thread.

Comment: Yes I did see that first question, but I thought it didn't apply here since the calls are sequential, and the animation call is the first call. I'll try what their solution and let you know what happens.

Comment: Ahh, okay. Now I feel stupid, but at least it works. Do you know why putting it on it's own thread makes it show up quicker?